# React native Unable to resolve module ./.expo/.virtual-metro-entry

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, react-hooks, expo

Actually I have installed unimodule previously was running react native cli because of tensorflow/tfjs-react-native I have to install unimodule but whenever I am doing yarn android I am getting below error
Error: Unable to resolve module ./.expo/.virtual-metro-entry from /home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/.:

None of these files exist:

- .expo/.virtual-metro-entry(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- .expo/.virtual-metro-entry/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
  at /home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21
  at Server._resolveRelativePath (/home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1045:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:449:37)
  at async Server._processRequest (/home/lipl-149/Desktop/Ankit/ReactJs/ReactNativeTry/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:383:7)

To able to do image expression recognition